# Installshield LE Spring 2012 Can't find setup prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield, installshield-2012

Here's the situation:

I have an InstallShield LE setup project (a couple actually) which have been working well for the last year.

Recently I configured a new laptop, thus reinstalled Visual Studio 2010 and Installshield LE.  Apparently, then updated InstallShield LE to the Spring 2012 edition.

Now when I attempt to build I get errors about missing setup prerequisites:

```
Error   7   -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer\3.1\x86\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' to target 'C:\Users\Erik\myProject\Server Install\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{57bcd1d4-2de9-49d9-bc0c-3f4263e9970e}\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'    ISEXP : error : -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites\Windows Installer\3.1\x86\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' to target 'C:\Users\Erik\myProject\Server Install\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{57bcd1d4-2de9-49d9-bc0c-3f4263e9970e}\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe'
```

Now, I've checked those file paths and lo and behold the files are not there.  Well, they're not exactly there.  It appears that they changed the path to these setup prerequisites in the Spring 2012 edition.

Now I've completely disassembled my .isl file.  Those file paths are not present anywhere in the .isl file; not absolute nor relative.  In fact, there are almost no file paths in the .isl file at all.

I've searched the internet thinking maybe I needed to upgrade my .isl file to be supported by Spring2012 edition, but those searches have not been fruitful.

I'm at the point where I'm just going to recreate the setup project, but boy would I love to find out what the heck went wrong.

Anybody else experience this issue when upgrading to the Spring 2012 edition of InstallShield LE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have received same error after upgrading VS2010 InstallShield project to VS2012.

```
Error   24  -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\3.5 SP1\Full\dotnetfx35.exe' to target 'D:\Users\...\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{074EE22F-2485-4FED-83D1-AAC36C3D9ED0}\dotnetfx35.exe'    ISEXP : error : -1007: Cannot copy source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites\Microsoft .net\3.5 SP1\Full\dotnetfx35.exe' to target 'D:\Users\...\Express\SingleImage\DiskImages\DISK1\ISSetupPrerequisites\{074EE22F-2485-4FED-83D1-AAC36C3D9ED0}\dotnetfx35.exe'
```

This problem solved by copying prerequisites from old InstallShield folder "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2011LE\SetupPrerequisites" to new "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2012SpringLE\SetupPrerequisites"

Comment: Thanks Neo Bit! I ended up doing exactly that  but forgot to answer my own question when I figured it out..

Answer (score 27):

It seems that InstallShield lost the path of your prerequisites.

A clean way to do it is to go to  "Redistributables" section of your installshild project ( 2- Specify Application Data / Redistributables ).

Normally Prerequisites you need should me marked "Needs to be downloaded".

Just download them with a Right Click directly on the table entry, and your problem will be fix .

I got the same problem when I opened a installshield project on a brand new machine. I had re-installed InstallShield of course, but Prerequisites were of course absent and needed to be donwloaded again.

Comment: Nice. I just ran into this. You can also select "Download all required items...". Seems to fetch everything required. You saved me a couple of hours in IS's nasty interface. Much better than the accepted answer. Thanks. +1

Answer (score 2):

We experienced a similar problem with the InstallShield Standalone Build. The build was failing and reporting that it could not copy a file from the SetupPrerequisites directory.

As flamandier answered the Redistributables need to be downloaded. This can be done by selecting the "Download Selected Item" or "Download All Required Items" option from the right-click menu on the Redistibutables View (under Application Data in the Installshield IDE). Or by using the Redistributable Downloader wizard found under the Tools menu option. See the flexera helpnet article  about the Redistributeable Downloader here http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/Wiz_RedistDownload.htm

For a stand-alone build the prerequisites need to be copied from from the machine running the full version of installshield. See the flexera helpnet article here http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/StandAloneBuild_Redists.htm

Answer (score 0):

Go to Property 
Common properties --> Project Dependencies --> Check Setup